# Ideas for a banana dessert crust, gluten free

Tags: gluten-free, children

I came across a nice little dessert consisting of sliced bananas sandwiching peanut butter. My kids would love it, but I have a youngin and he's gluten-free.  Worried handing him raw bananas as he'll a mush them up, so I want to put a crust of sorts on it to contain, or at least minimize the mushing. Chocolate is one alternative but  I'm leaning towards something a little healthier.

Comment: In my experience, no amount of crust will prevent mushing if mushing is what the youngin' wants to do...

Comment: Ha ha, so true, but I should make an attempt... I am thinking a graham cracker crust of sorts may go well, gotta find it gluten-free...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pamela's at http://www.pamelasproducts.com/products/baking-mixes/ makes a great non-gluten crust. I even added more coconut flour to it and mixed it in the food processor for a sweet potato pie. It came out firm and tasty. Also baked it first then added the filling and baked it again. If you add more flour you might want to add a little more salt but I like mine bland. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer is a gluten free graham cracker.
[http://www.amazon.com/Kinnikinnick-Foods-Smoreables-Graham-Crackers/dp/B004T3AWRA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004T3AWRA)

Most gluten free cookies and crackers tend to be pretty crumbly, so the additional moisture from the banana will help keep the treat from exploding into 1,000 crumbs.

Here's my favorite gluten free pie crust.
http://www.landolakes.com/recipe/3071/pie-crust-gluten-free-recipe
I use store bought flour blend.

Comment: We'd prefer that you stick to answering the question; the OP wasn't asking about cookie recipes, so I'll just edit that out. (In general we are a Q&A site, not a recipe swapping site, sorry.) The rest is really, helpful, though - upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I make those sometimes and I freeze them. They become more like popsicles, and they also aren't as prone to making a mess.

Just be sure to "flash freeze" them separately on a plate/cookie sheet so that they don't stick together.

Answer (score 0):

Cook's Country, America's Test Kitchen's sister show has a very interesting recipe from this season for a chocolate pie with a meringue crust.

The entire recipe and video is here: [Chocolate Angel Pie](http://www.cookscountry.com/recipes/7301-chocolate-angel-pie?extcode=MASKZ00L0&ref=search_results_2) That recipe is free right now (as of January 2015) because it's from this season. It will go behind a paywall next season. The site offers a 14 day free trial that includes all of their sites, which I totally recommend for all cooks to check out. You need a card to sign up, but they will not charge it if you cancel withing that 14 day window.

For the crust:

- 1 tablespoon cornstarch, plus extra for pie plate
- 1/2 cup (3 1/2 ounces) granulated sugar
- 3 large egg whites
- Pinch cream of tartar
- 1/2 teaspoon vanilla extract

> FOR THE MERINGUE CRUST: Adjust oven rack to lower-middle position and heat oven to 275 degrees. Grease 9-inch pie plate and dust well with extra cornstarch, using pastry brush to distribute evenly. Combine sugar and 1 tablespoon cornstarch in bowl. Using stand mixer fitted with whisk, whip egg whites and cream of tartar on medium-low speed until foamy, about 1 minute. Increase speed to medium-high and whip whites to soft, billowy mounds, 1 to 3 minutes. Gradually add sugar mixture and whip until glossy, stiff peaks form, 3 to 5 minutes. Add vanilla to meringue and whip until incorporated.
>
> Spread meringue into prepared pie plate, following contours of plate to cover bottom, sides, and edges. Bake for 1½ hours. Rotate pie plate, reduce oven temperature to 200 degrees, and bake until completely dried out, about 1 hour longer. (Shell will rise above rim of pie plate; some cracking is OK.) Let cool completely, about 30 minutes.

That would be a gluten free crust, interesting too. I want to try it.